# MongoDB Schema design with 3 tables

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am moving some of the code from MS SQL to MongoDb. In existing SQLSERVER i  have a Profile table , a Tag table and a ProfileTag table. Tag table contains all the available tags and ProfileTag table contains the tags for a specific user.

I need the ability to search Profiles by tags as well as Profile names.
So when i design the MongoDB Schema do i still need all 3 classes or can i remove ProfileTag from the list ? I am still trying to wrap my head around the document design.

```
public class Tag {

}

public class Profile {
    public Address Address {get;set;}
    public List<Education> EducationList {get;set;}
    public List<Tag> ProfileTags {get; set;}
}
```

Is this the correct approach in designing MongoDB schema ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

As per my experience I think your approach is in correct direction. You do not need the Profile tag as separate collection or class in C#. It can be simple array of strings. In mongodb schema may look like this. In the collection if your profile name is unique you can use it as _id which will be indexed automatically. mongoDB also allow to index the array so you can index on the key like Tags , which will improve the search of profiles based on the Tags. All the generic tags can be hold in another collection. One point you have keep in mind that in case of master tag is updated you have to bulk update all the profile tags as they are embedded in the profile collection

```
        {_id:  PROFILENAME , Tags : ["Tag1" , "Tag2" , "Tag3"] }
```

Comment: Thanks, is keeping the Tags documents outside the Profile document a good idea ? That means adding a ProfileTags table with a profileId in it.  The user can add or delete tags, but he can never update the master tag.

Comment: @user636525 See in case you keep your Profile Tags outside the profile collection , you will have to make two database call to show the Profile user with his/her tags. It also depends on what kind of query you are going to make.